# XML parsing to access tags

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I do have XML file, i would like to fetch the tags, edit the necessary element and write new file (updated XML).

```
<vdu xmlns="test:file">
<lsm>
    <m-id>v1</m-id>
    <name>v1</name>
    <communication>bi</communication>
    <states>
        <s-name>stage1</s-name>
        <state>
            <s-type>defaultState</s-type>
            <s-func>
                <p-name>pkgname</p-name>
                <f-list>
                    <f-name>funcNAME</f-name>
                    <f-arg>{&amp;}</f-arg>
                </f-list>
            </s-func>
        </state>
        <lib-path>libpath</lib-path>
        <e-list>
            <e-name>noEvent</e-name>
            <event>
                <nss>INC</nss>
                <nfs>INC</nfs>
                <actions>
                    <p-name>pkgName</p-name>
                    <f-list>
                        <f-name>toF</f-name>
                        <f-arg></f-arg>
                    </f-list>
                </actions>
            </event>
        </e-list>
```

however I am not able to get the text from the XML. I tried couple of things as below.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse(r'C:\Users\Sample\file.xml').getroot()

for child in root:
    print child.tag
    for child in child.iter('s-type'):
        print child
```

Output:

```
 <Element '{est:file}lsm
 []
```

Also, i tried with lxml(still exploring), didnt get expected answer. any help will be appreciated.

```
root.xpath("//lsm/states/e-list/e-name/text()")
```

output:

```
[]
```

however I am able to access values with `root[0][0].text`

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the fact that the elements are in a namespace. The "xmlns" declaration affects the name of every element in the document, and can't simply be ignored.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Thanks for the hint. I almost missed that.!