# find certain tags and write in new xml file

Tags: xml, python-2.7, elementtree

I want to find the `e-list` tag and write those in new xml file. xml is as below,

```
<lsm>
    <m-id>v1</m-id>
    <name>v1</name>
    <communication>bi</communication>
    <states>
        <s-name>stage1</s-name>
        <state>
            <s-type>defaultState</s-type>
            <s-func>
                <p-name>pkgname</p-name>
                <f-list>
                    <f-name>funcNAME</f-name>
                    <f-arg>{&amp;}</f-arg>
                </f-list>
            </s-func>
        </state>
        <lib-path>libpath</lib-path>
        <e-list>
            <e-name>noEvent</e-name>
            <event>
                <nss>INC</nss>
                <nfs>INC</nfs>
                <actions>
                    <p-name>pkgName</p-name>
                    <f-list>
                        <f-name>toF</f-name>
                        <f-arg></f-arg>
                    </f-list>
                </actions>
            </event>
        </e-list>
```

Here is my code,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

utree = ET.parse(r'C:\v1.xml')
uroot = utree.getroot()

for elist in uroot.iter('e-list'):
    print elist.tag                # print 3 Tags 
    for ename in elist.iter('e-name'):
        if (ename.text == 'noEvent' or 'Event'):
            print "test"        # Print "test" 3 times as i have 3 tags
            uroot.append(elist) #Commenting this line gives proper output.
utree.write('v2.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

This is going to infinity and not creating new file.

Comment: Your second for statement misses `in` between ename and elist.iter

Comment: @Vinny: Thanks for heads up. That was fine in my code. i messed up while copying. updated the code.

Comment: Just like in another question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/45791960/407651), you are ignoring the fact that the elements are in a namespace.

Comment: @mzjn : I already have taken care of namespace :) Missed to post updated xml in question (updated the Question).

Comment: Please provide complete code that we can copy-paste and run.

Comment: @mzjn : I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending new copies of `e-list` elements to the original root element over and over again. Instead you should create a new root element and append to that.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

utree = ET.parse('v1.xml')
newroot = ET.Element("lsm")

for elist in utree.iter('e-list'):
    for ename in elist.iter('e-name'):
        if (ename.text == 'noEvent' or 'Event'):
            newroot.append(elist) 

ET.ElementTree(newroot).write('v2.xml', xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
```